# Let $s,t$ be two group elements which commute with their commutator. Show that $(st)^n = (ts)^n [s,t]^m$ where $m$ is uniquely determined by $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Consider two elements $s,t \in G$ which commute with their commutator $[s,t] = sts^{-1}t^{-1}$. Show that $(st)^n = t^n s^n [s,t]^m$

I am mainly wondering about the approach to this problem. What I've done so far is attempted to use induction and just algebraic manipulation after that. I've tried this problem on and off for the past few weeks, and I'm just not getting anywhere. Is there a trick to it that I'm not seeing? Or will it just pop out after enough manipulation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that $st = [s,t]ts$. Since $[s,t]$ commutes with $s$ and $t$, we can move all instances of $[s,t]$ in a word to the end of the word.

So the problem reduces to: in the product $(st)^n = stst \cdots st$ how many times do we need to replace $st$ by $ts$ in order to change the word to $t^ns^n$. The number of such substitutions is the integer $m$ that you are trying to calculate.

It is clear that $m$ is a function of $n$ (which answers the question), but you might want to identify this function.

So, for $n=1$, starting with $st$ we need just one substitution, and for $n=2$, starting with $stst$, we need three.